# How can I handle some special character being returned as such on my razor page?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have the following razor syntax on my view page that will return a label as the following format: "Recherce d  & # 3 9 ;  address" but it should be: "Recherce d'address". This is caused by a é in my translation file.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">                        
@xxx.Tools.Language.Translate(xxx.Tools.Language.Keys.Address_Search, 
ViewBag):</label></div>
```

I'm not sure how to resolve the following syntax to prevent this. My intuition was to use HTML.Encode.Text but I'm getting lost with the syntax...

Comment: Use [@HTML.Raw(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Raw()` is your friend here. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Note that this presents a bit of a security risk in that if a user enters an address containing JavaScript, iFrame, etc they can produce an undesired effect.